# How to Mapping from JoinTable with Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, one-to-many

I have the following tables in my ERM/database:

**card**, **expansion** and **card_expansion**
`ManyToMany`-Relationship between card and expansion. A card can be in many expansions and an expansion can hold a many of cards.

**collection**
Description of how many cards from which expansion are needed. Card A from Expansion B is needed 3 times. So there's a `OneToMany` relationship to `card_expansion`.

I want to map these relations in my Entities-objects using Doctrine. Mapping between cards and expansions is no problem. 
But since the `card_expansion` table isn't mapped directly by an entity, I don't have a clue how to access it from my `Collection` entity or which annotation I have to use to build up that connection correctly...

What do I need to map to get this working?

Here's the code of my `Expansion` entity:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="expansion")
 */
class Expansion {

...
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Card")
     * @JoinTable(name="card_expansion",
     *     joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="_expansion", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="_card", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)})
     */
    private $cards;

    public function __construct () {
        $this->cards = new ArrayCollection();

    }
```

and here's my `Collection` Entity

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="collection")
 */
class Collection{

 /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="???")
     * @JoinTable(name="card_in_expansion")
     */
    private $card_in_expansion;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the relationship between `Card` and `Expension` to an entity `CardExpension`. Then you will be able to use it in your model.

Instead of having following:

`Card` - **ManyToMany** - `Expension`

You will get:

`Card` - **OneToMany** - `CardExpension` - **ManyToOne** - `Expension`

Read also on this [here in the Doctrine 2 documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional):

> Consequently, the direct many-to-many association disappears and is replaced by one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes.